# Choosing the right selection about previously submitted a paper in a journal

Tags: paper-submission

I have submitted my paper in a journal a week ago. After one week the administrator returned  my paper and requested all the authors to associate their ORCID with their accounts and asked us to resubmit the paper.
During the resubmission, a question asked "Was this paper previously submitted to this journal?" and I chose "No" as I thought this not a revision or a final version.
Now I see that it got an entirely new ID and is awaiting again for a new ADM to be assigned. I'm not sure if I had chosen "Yes", the previous ID with a .R1 (probably) would have been assigned with the same ADM so probably I haven't needed to wait again for a new ADM assignment; however, it's not a revision.

Overall, did I choose the correct option? If no, what should I do now? I'm not sure if it's the right action to contact the journal regarding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had chosen "yes", then presumably the editorial management system would give you some options that eventually return your submission to the original editor who was handling it, who would see that they'd asked you to indicate ORCID IDs and you've done so. If you chose "no", this wouldn't happen and they would treat it as a fresh submission, which might mean your submission reaches a different editor. So the answer is no, you did not choose the right option.

That said, it's not a big problem. Your submission could very well reach the original editor anyway (because their specialty matches yours the best). Even if it doesn't, modern editorial management systems are capable of flagging duplicate submissions, which should catch your paper. The journal staff would then fix any problems for you.

Accordingly I suggest doing nothing. If you're concerned, you could also email the journal (use the desk editor's email, not the editor-in-chief's), and they should handle it for you if they didn't already notice it.

Comment: The weird thing is that I contacted the ADM and he told that I chose the "right" option!

Comment: @Mohammad: You could write an email reply saying that on your screen the options are arranged vertically rather than horizontally. But don't send the email.

Comment: @Dave What do you mean by vertically and horizontally?

Comment: @Mohammad: I misread your comment and thought you said "and he told me that I **should choose** the "right" option. Given this misreading, here's what I meant: If the choices are arranged horizontally, then a "left-right description" makes sense, and if the choices are arranged vertically, then an "up-down description" makes sense. My point was that the ADM's reply is so uninformative that I thought you might appreciate thinking about "returning the favor" (sarcasm intended) by pretending to completely misunderstand what you were told. But it seems this is not what what happened . . .

Answer (score 1):

Often the journal submission system will have something like the following:

[image: new journal submission options]

When the administrative staff send it back to you, your manuscript will usually show up in "submission sent back to author". Thus usually, you would edit this version of your submission. This generally avoids the issue of getting a new submission ID.

One minor procedural issue  would be if you submitted a "new manuscript" when you were meant to update the "submission sent back to author".

That said, there are a range of journal submission systems.
Most likely, it wont matter and the administrative assistants will let you know what they need.

Comment: Thanks. Next to my primary submission, it's written "a resubmission has been submitted (WITH THE NEW ID)". So as mentioned, I think the ADM (if the original guy is aware of that) figures that out.

Comment: Just to be clear, could you please let me know what that question exactly means? And in what cases should one select the "Yes" option. For example, if a paper gets rejected with encouragement to update and resubmit, should one select the "Yes" option in the next submission?